# Gulp inject ignores css if the dist folder was first cleaned

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-inject

I have a simple gulp script. The flow is:

1. delete dist folder
2. move .html and .css files to the new dist folder
3. compile typescript and move generated .js to dist folder
4. mimify the .js
5. inject .js and .css into .html

The problem is that if I first delete the dist folder, the injection works only for .js files. However if I skip the cleaning of dist folder it creates a correct .html (as in both .js and .css are present in index.html). Has any one encountered this problem? If so, how have you fixed it? I am guessing it has something to do with pipelining.

Gulp version: "^3.9.1"

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var del = require('del');

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
    gulp.start('scripts')
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    del(['dist'], cb)
});

gulp.task('move', function () {
    console.log('-- gulp is running task "move"');
    gulp.src(['app/**/*.html', 'app/**/*.css'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('compile', ['move'], function () {
    console.log('-- gulp is running task "compile"');
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(ts({
            noImplicitAny: true,
            out: 'app.js'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('compress', ['compile'], function () {
    console.log('-- gulp is running task "compress"');
    gulp.src('dist/**/*.js')
        .pipe(minify({
            ext: {
                src: '-debug.js',
                min: '.js'
            },
            noSource: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});


gulp.task('scripts', ['compress'], function () {
    console.log('-- gulp is running task "scripts"');
    var target = gulp.src('dist/index.html');
    var sources = gulp.src(['dist/**/*.js', 'dist/**/*.css'], {read: false});
    return target.pipe(inject(sources, {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into race conditions because you're not properly signalling [async completion](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support) in several places:

[`del`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) doesn't take a callback `cb`, it returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You need to return that Promise from your task:

```
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del(['dist']);
});
```

Streams need to be returned from your tasks as well. You're not doing that in your `move` and `compress` tasks which (among other things) means that `gulp-inject` might run before all `.css` files have been copied over to `dist/`.

```
gulp.task('move', function () {
  console.log('-- gulp is running task "move"');
  return gulp.src(['app/**/*.html', 'app/**/*.css'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})

gulp.task('compress', ['compile'], function () {
  console.log('-- gulp is running task "compress"');
  return gulp.src('dist/**/*.js')
    .pipe(minify({
        ext: {
            src: '-debug.js',
            min: '.js'
        },
        noSource: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks! Just to note, apparently I was using old version of del (as in 1.1.0) in which the del takes a callback function. I have upgraded it and added returns to 'compress' and 'move' and it works like charm.